# Understanding Google Mail API Quotas

Tags: email, google-app-engine

I can't make any sense of the official quotas for using the Mail API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas?csw=1#Mail

Looks like I can make 7,000 API calls/day or 32 calls/minute, but I can only send 8 message/minute. So I should make either 1 API call/minute sending 8 emails, or make 8 API calls/minute each sending 1 email?

Are developers really supposed to drip messages at a rate of 8 emails per minute?

Answer (score 1):

> So I should make either 1 API call/minute sending 8 emails, or make 8 API calls/minute each sending 1 email?

Either of them is fine, do whatever makes sense for your app (within the quota limits).

> Are developers really supposed to drip messages at a rate of 8 emails per minute?

For a large number of apps this is more than enough. For those which need more than that alternative solutions are available. See [GAE increase recepients emailed limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122113/gae-increase-recepients-emailed-limit/45124542#45124542).