# Google App Engine Mail Quota is Ambiguous

Tags: email, google-app-engine, quota

The Quota page states a limit for a free quota of 10 mail recipients.
It's not clear to me if that is distinct email addresses or not.  If not, then is it really just 10 messages.
I'm testing an app where I'm sending emails to just one address.
But I just got a message of quota exceeded.  My account stats shows 11 recipients, which suggests that it's not based on distinct addresses.   This isn't making much sense to me.  And just 10 messages seems a very low limit.

A limit of only 10 emails seems quite inconsistent with allowing 7,000 Mail API calls.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From [Mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Mail):

> App Engine bills for email use "by message," counting each email to
>   each recipient. For example, sending one email to ten recipients
>   counts as 10 messages.

Note the quotas and usage values being counted in `messages` or `mails`, not `recipients`.

The same is true even for the `Recipients` and `Admins` quotas (as displayed in the developer console screen, in the above documentation they're actually referred to as `Messages sent` and `Admins Messages Sent`):

> **Messages sent**
>
> The total number of messages that have been sent by the application.
>   Note that the maximum quota for messages sent stays at free levels
>   until the first charge for your application has cleared.
>
> **Admins Messages Sent**
>
> The total number of messages to application admins that have been sent
>   by the application. (The total size limit for each admin email,
>   including headers, attachments, and body, is 16KB).

and

> ```
> Resource              Free default limit
>
> Recipients emailed    10 messages
> Admins emailed        5,000 mails
> ```

I can see why the 10 vs 7000 emails/calls may appear inconsistent - naming is a bit questionable. The `Free default limit` simply means the default limit for the Free apps - as in apps without billing enabled (vs.
the `Billing enabled default limit` which is the default limit for apps with billing enabled).

As for the low limit, see [GAE increase recipients emailed limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122113/gae-increase-recepients-emailed-limit/45124542#45124542)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess part of the reason for 7000 calls is the 5000 emails to Admins - and I have no idea what would be for or why so high.  Anyway ....  I did check SendGrid but there's a small gocha ... to subscribe to the FREE quota there you have to have billing enabled!!!   (I havent enabled it because Im pretty inexperienced at this stuff and don't want to risk any expensive accidents on what is basically a hobby.  I'll check the other two - then it may be tome for alternate cat skinning techniques!

Comment: If/when you decide to enable billing (several features require it) you can keep costs in check by setting a max [daily spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit). It's actually a good idea to do it anyways, I did see in the past reported problems somehow related to the daily budget left at 0.